# WebSockets y .net

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, socket

Estoy intentando realizar una aplicación de .Net Framework que se conecta a mi servidor de WebSockets hecho en JavaScript, mi problema es que cuando ocurre un evento desde el servidor mi cliente no responde, pero si el evento ocurre desde el cliente el servidor si responde. Creo que mi problema es el servidor de WebSockets pero no estoy seguro. Si tienen la respuesta en VB.NET O C# no hay ningún problema puedo traducir ese código a mi necesidad, muchas gracias de ante mano.

**Codigo del Servidor de Sockets**

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log('new connection id: '+ ws)
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });
  ws.on('close',(ws)=>{
    console.log('connection close')
  })
  ws.on('typing',()=>{
    console.log('escribiendo')
  })
  ws.on('stop typing',()=>{
    console.log('no escribiendo')
  })
  ws.emit("message","Hola");
  
  ws.send('something');
});
```

**Codigo de mi cliente de VB.NET**

```
Public Async Sub Connect()
    Using [client] = New H.Socket.IO.SocketIoClient()
            AddHandler client.Connected, Sub(sender, args) Console.WriteLine("Connected: " + args.Namespace)
            AddHandler client.Disconnected, Sub(sender, args) Console.WriteLine("Disconnected")
            AddHandler client.EventReceived, Sub(sender, args) Console.WriteLine("EventReceived: " + args.Value)
            AddHandler client.ErrorReceived, Sub(sender, args) Console.WriteLine("ErrorReceived: " + args.Value)
            AddHandler client.ExceptionOccurred, Sub(sender, args) Console.WriteLine("ExceptionOccurred: " + args.Value.ToString())

            client.On("message", Sub(message)
                                     Console.WriteLine("You are logged in. Total number of users: ")
                                 End Sub)
            client.On(Of ChatMessage)("user joined", Sub(message)
                                                         Console.WriteLine("User joined: " + message.Username)
                                                     End Sub)
            client.On(Of ChatMessage)("user left", Sub(message)
                                                       Console.WriteLine("User left: " + message.Username)
                                                   End Sub)
            client.On(Of ChatMessage)("typing", Sub(message)
                                                    Console.WriteLine("User typing: " + message.Username)
                                                End Sub)
            client.On(Of ChatMessage)("stop typing", Sub(message)
                                                         Console.WriteLine("User stop typing: " + message.Username)
                                                     End Sub)
            client.On(Of ChatMessage)("new message", Sub(message)
                                                         Console.WriteLine("New message: " + message.Message)
                                                     End Sub)

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting...")

            Await client.ConnectAsync(New Uri("http://localhost:3000"))
            Await client.Emit("message", "Hola")
            Console.WriteLine("reser...")
            Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            Await client.Emit("typing")
            Console.WriteLine("typing...")
            Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            Await client.Emit("new message", "hello")
            Console.WriteLine("new message...")
            Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            Await client.Emit("stop typing")
            Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        End Using
    End Sub
```